# Good Entity Manager Handling - C# XNA/MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm quite new to MonoGame/XNA and for my first actual game, i thought I would try and recreate space invaders. To handle the invaders movement, I created a "InvaderManager" class to handle all this. I then created another class called "EntityManager" to handle all other kinds of entities such as bullets.

This works alright though those classes can only be accessed within my "MainGame" class which handles the actual game meaning if for example when I want the collision code in the "Bullet" class to remove an invader when it's collided with one (meaning it has to access the "InvaderManager" class), it becomes a little awkward and has basically lead to me making functions in these manager classes static so outside classes can access call them without an instance.

```
for(int i = 0; i < InvaderManager.spaceInvaders.Count; i++)
        {
            if(CollisionDetect(InvaderManager.spaceInvaders[i]))
            {
                EntityManager.Remove(this);
                InvaderManager.Remove(InvaderManager.spaceInvaders[i]);
            }
        }
```

This works of course but something is telling me this isn't a good way to go about it so I thought I would ask this forum if there is possibly a better way I could handle all this? Or is it alright to make certain function static for the purpose I stated?

Comment: Don't handle that logic inside each class, that logic should be handled inside your game engine. That will make your code faster and you don't have these problems.

Answer (score 0):

When you make state globally visible and modifiable, soon various code will be accessing and modifying that state, and it will become difficult to make code changes without affecting the entire program.

Restrict visibility as much as it makes sense to.

Static functions are perfectly fine. Global static state (like a static public array) is usually not.

If you're not sure what a class should be doing, don't write that class. Your `InvaderManager` seems to be little more than a list of entities. Just use a `List` then.

Good object-oriented design is hard, and you don't need it for space invaders. Think of your problem in terms of data types and functions rather than manager classes.

It's difficult to give you more specific advice with such a general question.